# How should JWT tokens be made?

Tags: account-security, jwt

I'm writing a simple website to help me grasp cybersecurity practices and I decided to stick to JWT tokens, but I have no idea about what I should write on the payload.

I've seen on many JWT token generators "Claim email, domain, etc.", but why is that necessary? Couldn't the user's UUID just be stored there and other information be looked up server-side?

Comment: Yes, that works as well.

Comment: Have you looked this up? https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html and https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#token-explicit-revocation-by-the-user and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

Comment: @Theonewhotests So it's more of a standard than a security requirement?

Comment: @schroeder never thought to look up owasp standards, thanks!

Comment: If you want to get a grasp on web security, your first stop should be OWASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of a JWT (for first-party authentication) is that you don't look up anything server-side. It's stateless, meaning the server doesn't have to store any state about user login sessions. This is good for scalability, but comes with a bunch of complications.

Unless you're aiming for the kind of extreme scalability that requires stateless sessions, or you want to separate your authentication functionality from your application functionality (e.g. use SSO), don't use JWTs. They add complexity and slightly weaken security (can't really revoke them so no good way to end a session prematurely). A simple cryptographically-secure random string - which is the indexed key to a server-side session table wherein you can find out who the user is and anything else you want to store for the session - is the tried and true method for generating tokens in a scenario like that.

---

With all that said, yes, you absolutely *can* just store a user ID in the JWT payload, and look up what that means on the server. It's inefficient and arguably the worst of both worlds in terms of performance, complexity, and security... but you can do it.